# Send Email Using CodeIgniter 3.1.10

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want send email using codeigniter, i see how make this in internet. but when i write the code, email not send to people.

using codeigniter 3.1.10

```
private function _sendEmail(){
  $config = [
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_user' => '****',
    'smtp_pass' => '****',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'crlf'      => "\r\n"
  ];
  $this->load->library('email',$config);
  $this->email->from('vcopadangpariaman@gmail.com','VCO Padang Pariaman');
  $this->email->to('taufikleon44@gmail.com');
  $this->email->subject('Testing');
  $this->email->message("hallo");
  if($this->email->send()){
    return true;
  }else {
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
  }
}
```

i want send email to taufikleon44@gmail.com

Comment: sory i bad write in english

Comment: are these real user and passwords? if yes, you are compromising that email account!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe because of the wrong username and password given in SMTP authentication or SMTP port blocked in mail server firewalls.

If you are using Gmail account, please check this link and turn off the "Allow less secure apps".

Here is the URL: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Then try to send email again.

I have updated your code and check now:

```
private function _sendEmail() {
        $config = [
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_user' => '****',
            'smtp_pass' => '****',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_timeout' => '20',
            'validation' => TRUE,
            'newline' => "\r\n"
        ];
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('vcopadangpariaman@gmail.com', 'VCO Padang Pariaman');
         $this->email->to('taufikleon44@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Testing');
        $this->email->message("hallo");
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
    }
```